# How can I eliminate "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'" error as follows?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

When I run the following code,

```
def difference(dataset, interval=1):
    diff = list()
    for i in range(interval, len(dataset)):
        value = dataset[i] - dataset[i - interval]
        diff.append(value)
    return numpy.array(diff)

series = read_csv('Houston_weather.csv', header=None)
X = series.values
days_in_year = 365
differenced = difference(X, days_in_year)
```

I get the following error, is there a way to eliminate it? I am working on time series of weather.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-a0a67d687691> in <module>
      4 X = series.values
      5 days_in_year = 365
----> 6 differenced = difference(X, days_in_year)

<ipython-input-64-b7e841922d29> in difference(dataset, interval)
      3     diff = list()
      4     for i in range(interval, len(dataset)):
----> 5         value = dataset[i] - dataset[i - interval]
      6         diff.append(value)
      7     return numpy.array(diff)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

My data frame is:
[image]

Comment: You call it `series`, but read_csv normally produces a dataframe.  What's the nature of `X`?  `shape`?  `dtype`?  If `object`, what do the values look like?

Comment: I have added my data frame.

Comment: Your first column is dates, as strings.  You can't subtract those.  You might be able to convert them to pandas datatime objects that do support subtraction.  Check the pandas documentation.

Answer (score 2):

It simply says that "you are trying to use **-** operator between 2 strings". You should convert them to number.

`value = int(dataset[i]) - int(dataset[i - interval])` might help if they are integers.

`value = float(dataset[i]) - float(dataset[i - interval])` might help if they are floats.

Also, the documentation of pandas says that it is better to use `to_numpy()` instead of `values`.

> Warning We recommend using DataFrame.to_numpy() instead.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html

Comment: What if `dataset` is a 2d object dtype array?

Comment: `astype` function of numpy can be used. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html I didn't think throughly

Answer (score 0):

You have error in this line:

> ----> 5         value = dataset[i] - dataset[i - interval]

Reason for your error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Thing is you need to `cast` the values to `int` (or any other numeric types like `long`, `float`, `double`, etc. based on your dataset) to perform this computation.

You can cast the values from `string` to `int` like this and rerun your application:

```
value = int(dataset[i]) - int(dataset[i - interval])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think either of you is taking into account the `pandas` dataframe source. @canbax.

Answer (score 0):

To give a proper answer, I need some idea of what you `csv` file is like, or if you prefer the `series` or `X` variables.

But I can make some reasonable guesses - if only for educational purposes.

Start with a simple single column file (since you call the output `series):

```
In [82]: data = pd.read_csv('stack59728678.csv', header=None)                                    
In [83]: data                                                                                    
Out[83]: 
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
In [84]: X = data.values                                                                         
In [85]: X                                                                                       
Out[85]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5]])
In [86]: X.shape                                                                                 
Out[86]: (5, 1)
In [87]: X[3]-X[1]                                                                               
Out[87]: array([2])
```

So if the `csv` data is numeric, the dataframe will be numeric, as will the array.  This subtraction works fine.

## with label column

Lets expand the file to include a 'label' column:

```
a, 1
b, 2
c, 3
d, 4
e, 5
```

Now the load is a 2 column dataframe:

```
In [88]: data = pd.read_csv('stack59728678.csv', header=None)                                    
In [89]: data                                                                                    
Out[89]: 
   0  1
0  a  1
1  b  2
2  c  3
3  d  4
4  e  5
In [90]: X = data.values                                                                         
In [91]: X                                                                                       
Out[91]: 
array([['a', 1],
       ['b', 2],
       ['c', 3],
       ['d', 4],
       ['e', 5]], dtype=object)
In [92]: X.shape                                                                                 
Out[92]: (5, 2)
In [93]: X[3]-X[1]                                                                               
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-93-d04faaa95e8e> in <module>
----> 1 X[3]-X[1]

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

this is your error message.  It's trying to subtract the string 'b' from 'd'.

The other answers suggested applying the `int` function to convert the strings to numbers:

```
In [94]: int(X[3])-int(X[1])                                                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-ec49f350c7b3> in <module>
----> 1 int(X[3])-int(X[1])

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

But a row of `X` is an array, and doesn't work as input to the `int` function:

```
In [95]: X[3]                                                                                    
Out[95]: array(['d', 4], dtype=object)
```

Look at the `info` or `dtypes` of dataframe:

```
In [98]: data.info()                                                                             
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 2 columns):
0    5 non-null object
1    5 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 208.0+ bytes
```

A working solution will depend on the data.  In this example we could extract the numeric column(s):

```
In [100]: X=data[1].to_numpy()                                                                   
In [101]: X                                                                                      
Out[101]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

In other cases it might be possible to convert the object column strings to numbers, or 'date' types that implement subtraction.

## with dates

Changing the file to include the dates:

```
In [104]: data = pd.read_csv('stack59728678.csv', header=None)                                   
In [105]: data                                                                                   
Out[105]: 
            0  1
0  2009-01-01  1
1  2009-01-02  2
2  2009-01-03  3
3  2009-01-04  4
4  2009-01-05  5
In [106]: data.info()                                                                            
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 2 columns):
0    5 non-null object
1    5 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 208.0+ bytes
```

We still have the strings.  But we change that column:

```
In [107]: data[0].astype('datetime64[D]')                                                        
Out[107]: 
0   2009-01-01
1   2009-01-02
2   2009-01-03
3   2009-01-04
4   2009-01-05
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]
In [108]: data[0]=data[0].astype('datetime64[D]')                                                
In [109]: data.info()                                                                            
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 2 columns):
0    5 non-null datetime64[ns]
1    5 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(1)
memory usage: 208.0 bytes
```

The `X` is still object dtype, but it has `Timestep` objects instead of strings, and subtraction is possible:

```
In [110]: X=data.to_numpy()                                                                      
In [111]: X                                                                                      
Out[111]: 
array([[Timestamp('2009-01-01 00:00:00'), 1],
       [Timestamp('2009-01-02 00:00:00'), 2],
       [Timestamp('2009-01-03 00:00:00'), 3],
       [Timestamp('2009-01-04 00:00:00'), 4],
       [Timestamp('2009-01-05 00:00:00'), 5]], dtype=object)
In [112]: X[3]-X[1]                                                                              
Out[112]: array([Timedelta('2 days 00:00:00'), 2], dtype=object)
```